# Regex - aways separate operands with operators

Tags: regex

I would like to validate my infix notation through regex. Right now I have something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|( [\+\-\/\*]))*( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$
```

I check if the expresion starts and ends with operands. In the middle i can have operands or operators always devided by single space. There could be only one operator and operands can have multiple characters. Everything seems to be ok for now. But I would also like to check if operands are always separated by operator and I have no idea how to achieve that. Could someone give me some advice?

Comment: Do you mean [`^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?: *[+\-\/*] *[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/LZIWcV/1/)?

Comment: yes, thank you it works. Could you add it as answer so I could mark it? Also could you explain what does '?' do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following fix:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?: *[+\/*-] *[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LZIWcV/2).

Note that depending on the regex library you may or may not use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, as in .NET or Python 3.x `\w` is Unicode aware by default.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, digits or `_`
- `(?: *[+\/*-] *[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `*[+/*-] *` - zero or more space, an operator, 0+ spaces,
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, digits or `_`
- `$` - end of string.

Note that in case your regex flavor is not using regex delimiters, there is no point escaping `/`. To match any whitespace, replace the regular space in the pattern with `\s`.

The `(?:...)` construct is a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do). It is meant to *group* patterns, either alternations (like `(?:abc|xyz)`) or quantified (like here), or both. The value it matches is not stored anywhere, you cannot access it after a match is found (unlike the capturing group).